# what is the best facedetection .net other than luxand

Tags: c#, face-detection

i would like to know the best 
face detection software

i tried luxand facesdk but its very too much. 4000usd per process per year.

so what is the alternative for .NET , ASP.NET or MVC

Comment: This question is subjective and not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `OpenCV` library

Link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23191/Face-and-Eyes-Detection-Using-OpenCV